# MYSQL- Query to search using 'like' but searching only specific columns

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using this query to select data:

```
mysql_query("select * from tenders where Heading LIKE '%{$key}%' OR Date LIKE '%{$key}%'");
```

now there is a field `status` which indicates whether tender is online or offline i.e shown on website or hidden.

I want to select only those tenders whose status is online.
Can anyone help me with this? I am unable to use multiple where clause `where status=online`

How can I write query for this?

Comment: Could you please elaborate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't write *multiple `WHERE` clauses*, you write *multiple conditions* in the `WHERE` clause.  (Exactly like your query *already does* with the two `LIKE` comparisons, though perhaps with some parentheses to specify the logic a little more explicitly.)  Something like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tenders
WHERE
  (Heading LIKE '%{$key}%' OR Date LIKE '%{$key}%')
  AND status = 'online'
```

Also, I think you mean that `status` is a *column*, not a *row*.  Otherwise, this whole thing becomes much more confusing...

Comment: yes i am really sorry its a column.. and thanks it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tenders WHERE Heading = '%{$key}%' OR Date = '%{$key}%'");
```

Using WHERE x = y OR z = a should work in your case, I am a little confused on exactly what you want but this should help!